# Testing React Native Hook with Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, jestjs

I've got a basic React Native app that has been barely modified and initialized using [Expo](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup):

```
expo init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
yarn start
```

The initialized app has this class:

```
import {
  ColorSchemeName,
  useColorScheme as _useColorScheme,
} from "react-native";

export default function useColorScheme(): NonNullable<ColorSchemeName> {
  return _useColorScheme() as NonNullable<ColorSchemeName>;
}
```

I'm going through the codebase and trying to add unit tests. I've added a few rendering tests for React Native components, but here I'm trying to unit test the `useColorScheme()` function. Since this is a React hook, I can't call it outside of a React function body.

```
// Using jest
import useColorScheme from "../useColorScheme";

it('useColorScheme', () => {
    const huh = useColorScheme();
});
```

So basically my question is - What's the best way to call a React hook using jest since the hooks can only be called from a React function? (Let it be noted that I am quite new to javascript, typescript, and React)

Comment: I'm not sure what's the relation between the title and the body of your post. "./ios: No such file or directory" seems unrelated to testing hooks. Would you be able to clarify?

Comment: In regards to testing React hooks, you would have to run them inside a component. You could construct the component in the test itself. Or use utilities, such as [`react-hooks-testing-library`](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library), which do this for you.

Comment: @Wing

Thank you, I'll fix that. StackOverflow cached a previous draft and when I came to ask a different question, I forgot to change the title. I will fix the title to be something relevant.

Comment: @Wing Alright, I used the react-hooks-testing-library to cook something up: `const { result } = renderHook(() => useColorScheme());` and then `expect(["light", "dark"]).toContain(result.current);`